# main() inside a class vs. main() inside an interface

Tags: java, interface, program-entry-point

My question is whether main() inside an interface has any benefit over main() inside a class.

```
public interface Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really, you can do it either way actually, but very unusual to put it inside an interface.

Comment: The only difference maybe is that the class file generated with `interface` case has `ACC_INTERFACE, ACC_ABSTRACT` flags.

Comment: I would vote to reopen the question if I could, since this question doesn't ask WHY it is possible but WHAT BENEFIT one would get from either option. Which is different.

Comment: Actually there could be. Let me update my answer...... (anyway I kinda agree) (...and edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 allows static methods within interfaces.

This is the only reason having main() within an interface has become possible, while it previously wasn't.

To nitpick, main within interface gives it access_flags ACC_INTERFACE and ACC_ABSTRACT (since interface methods should be implemented). This means you could implement main() also within your class, creating confusion.

For this reason, plus the merely accidental course of events that made main() within interface possible, I would recommend using main() within class.

Apart from that, using main() within class or within interface makes no difference.

---

#### Possible benefit of main() within interface

Since main() is quite program-specific, there is only a use case it would be convenient to have a... `Mainable` interface: **debug**.
Given a generic enough main() and proper arguments, you could use it as a driver to debug classes by turning them "Mainable", one at a time, and save time avoiding to rewrite a main() for each class. You could recycle the code.

While it is a little borderline and probably not worth the effort to keep all `Mainable` classes compatible with this main(), it could be done. This is a possibility to illustrate.

Comment: I would be open to constructive criticism if the downvoter kindly wrote a comment.